# Copy Column Value from One table into Another Matching IDs

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
 t1
        id  |  value
        1   |   -
        2   |   -
 t2
       parent_id  |  p_value
        1         |   254
        2         |   124
```

I want to copy the column `p_value` from t2 into t1 where `parent_id = id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update t1, t2 set t1.value = t2.p_value where t1.id=t2.parent_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   Update t1, t2 set t1.value = t2.p_value where t1.id = t2.parent_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update t1 join t2 on t2.parent_id= t1.id set t1.value = t2.p_value
```