# Copy Column Value from One table into Another Matching IDs - SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, set, sql-update

I want to do exactly what it was described in this question: ([Copy Column Value from One table into Another Matching IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562920/copy-column-value-from-one-table-into-another-matching-ids)), but in SQLite instead of MySQL.

The solution provided:

```
update t1, t2 set t1.value = t2.p_value where t1.id=t2.parent_id
```

returns an error near ","... If I say

```
update t1 set t1.value = t2.p_value where t1.id=t2.parent_id
```

returns an error near "."

I was not expecting the syntax of MySQL being so different from SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
UPDATE t1 
SET  t1.value = ( 
     SELECT t2.p_value 
     FROM t2 
     WHERE t1.id = t2.parent_id)
```

or  using you code  try

```
UPDATE t1 
SET value = ( 
  SELECT value 
  FROM t2 
  WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: Might it be because in my original data p_value and value have the same name and id and parent_id also have the same name? UPDATE t1 
SET t1.value = (
 SELECT t2.value 
 FROM t2 
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: following up on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268592/sqlite-update-table-matching-unique-ids-dont-look-again-for-the-same-id-once/58269441?noredirect=1#comment102906209_58269441